# Using Firestore instead of Firebase with ionic - runtime error an attempt was made to open a lower version

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I try to use Firestore instead of Firebase with ionic 3. It is my second try.  A few months ago it worked well but for some reason, i continued my project with firebase RTDB.  Now I want to switch to Firestore again.  I followed all tutorials provided by Google and many others.
I get a runtime error in my component. The runtime error message is :

> "An attempt was made to open a database using a lower version than the
>   existing version"

It appends at the constructor, I don't understand what happened and find nothing regarding this issue.

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

...

```
prodcollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this.afs.collection('products');

  prodobs = this.prodcollection.valueChanges();

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}
```

My setup :

```
ionic Framework : 3.9.2
ionic app-script : 3.1.4
Angular-core : 5.0.3
Node 7.8.0
...
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "firebase": "^4.8.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
"firebase": "4.8.0"
```

in your setup instead of 4.8.2